# Creating base table and extend from it in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am currently attempting to build a very simple CMS in Laravel, such that I have a basic `entities` table (and model), with structure as follows:

```
{
    id: int,
    slug: string
}
```

And several other tables (`pages`, `blogposts`, etc), with a structure similar to the following:

```
{
    id: int,
    title: string,
    content: string,
    entity_id: int
}
```

The idea being that the app gets the URL, finds an entity that matches the slug, and then *finds the corresponding `Page`, `Blogpost`, etc.*

It's that last step that I can't figured out how to achieve. Should I add a `model_name` column to the `entities` table, so I can know which `Model` to query?  I have looked into polymorphic relationships, but I don't think they're necessarily what I'm looking for, as this is very much a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Can i know the need for storing the slug in a separate table? To answer your question, you just need a `hasOne` relationship on your `Page` and `BlogPost` model to make use of the `Entity` model.

Comment: Hi @Sandeesh, so I get my entity object via `Entity::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();`.. How do I then go about getting the `Page`, `BlogPost` etc object associated with that `Entity`?

Comment: I've added my answer to explain this better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question you need to do this.

In Page and BlogPost model

```
public function entity()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Entity');
}
```

In Entity model

```
public function page()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Page');
}

public function blogPost()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\BlogPost');
}
```

Controller logic

```
$entity = Entity::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
$page = $entity->page;
$blogPost = $entity->blogPost;

// OR

$page = Page::whereHas('entity', function ($query) use ($slug) {
    $query->where('slug', $slug);
})->get();

$blogPost = BlogPost::whereHas('entity', function ($query) use ($slug) {
    $query->where('slug', $slug);
})->get();
```

But ideally this is a bad implementation. You should go with storing the id of the page or blog post in the entity table using polymorphic relationship. Then reference the page or blog post using this after filtering with the slug.

You could rename the entity table to slugs to make more sense.

```
slugs
    id - integer
    name - string
    slugable_id - integer
    slugable_type - string
```

This eliminates you to check if the entity has a page or blogpost and directly fetch the related model.